# React Deleting checkbox item from list, strange behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my component:

[image]

After clicking delete, the checkbox underneath it becomes checked, even though it was never clicked.

[image]

Here is the parent and child component implementations (new to React)

> TaskList.js

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Task from "./Task";
function TaskList({ className, tasks, setTasks }) {
  let inputRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <ul className="grow overflow-y-scroll">
        {tasks.map((task, i) => (
          <Task
            description={task.description}
            onChange={() => {
              task.checked = !task.checked;
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        className="my-2 border-b-2 border-blue-300"
        placeholder="Enter task description..."
        ref={inputRef}
      ></input>
      <button
        className="rounded-md bg-blue-400 w-full p-4 text-white text-2xl"
        onClick={() => {
          setTasks([
            ...tasks,
            { description: inputRef.current.value, checked: false },
          ]);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <button
        className="w-full bg-red-600 rounded-md p-2"
        onClick={() => {
          setTasks(tasks.filter((t) => !t.checked));
        }}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TaskList;
```

> Task.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Task({ description, onChange }) {
  return (
    <li className="flex flex-row my-2">
      <input className="mx-2" type="checkbox" onChange={onChange}></input>
      <span>{description}</span>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is why keys are so important when rendering lists - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: @BrianThompson Hi, I just added a key to the Task component (the index of the map function).  Unfortunately the behavior persists.

Comment: Yep. That's because if a key is omitted, React defaults to the index anyway. So nothing has actually changed.

Comment: @BrianThompson Ok, I will try adding a uuid package to my project and generating a unique key that way and see if it helps.

Comment: React identifies components by that key, so when you remove an element at *any* position in the array, the key that now is missing will *always* be the last one. Therefore, even though you deleted a different element, React sees that the last one is what should be removed

Comment: Be careful doing the UUID trick. You could end up with a different problem that's even harder to diagnose. I'll write up an answer or try to find an existing one to point you to

Comment: @BrianThompson Please do.  I just added the uuid package and that fixed the problem.  Will mark your response as the answer when you post it, thanks.

Comment: The existing answer will do just fine as long as your descriptions are unique (they probably should be). So I'll just give a final warning about the UUID (or `Math.random`) strategy of solving this problem - generating a key on each render will cause *all* of the components to unmount and be recreated. This will "fix" the problem, but will be poor performing. It also has the potential to cause bugs if those components have state or use lifecycle methods/hooks. If you go this route, be sure to assign the UUID *once* to an element when it gets added to state

Comment: @BrianThompson Perfect.  Such a helpful comment honestly.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing keys from the Task component, and you're using uncontrolled components, so when there's a re-render, you aren't telling React enough about which element that exists in the DOM corresponds to which `<Task>`. The best fix would be to:

- Use controlled components instead of uncontrolled components; components are generally more predictable and useable with state, since the view should flow from the state. (If you use controlled components, you can also avoid from having to resort to a ref). Both the text input and the checkboxes can be made controlled.
- Use keys when returning from `.map`
- Don't mutate state in React; `task.checked = !task.checked;` should be refactored.

Something along the lines of:

```
function TaskList({ className, tasks, setTasks }) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(''); // <-------------------
  
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <ul className="grow overflow-y-scroll">
          {tasks.map((task, i) => (
            <Task
              key={task.description} // <-------------------
              description={task.description}
              checked={task.checked} // <-------------------
              onChange={() => {
                setTasks( // <-------------------
                  tasks.map(
                    (task, j) => i !== j ? task : { ...task, checked: !task.checked }
                  )
                );
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <input
          className="my-2 border-b-2 border-blue-300"
          placeholder="Enter task description..."
          value={value} // <-------------------
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)} // <-------------------
        ></input>
        <button
          className="rounded-md bg-blue-400 w-full p-4 text-white text-2xl"
          onClick={() => {
            setTasks([
              ...tasks,
              { description: value, checked: false }, // <-------------------
            ]);
          }}
        >
        ...
```

```
function Task({ description, onChange, checked }) { // <-------------------
  return (
    <li className="flex flex-row my-2">
      <input className="mx-2" type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} checked={checked} />  // <-------------------
      <span>{description}</span>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this.  Very helpful.  I had been passing a checked prop down to Task previously, but was running into a different issue beforehand.  But your changes to TaskList will probably fix the issue I was having earlier (unrelated to the problem in my post, however).  

This would run into an issue if two Tasks has the same description I would imagine.  I can check before adding them to the tasks array to make sure it is not a duplicate description, so that would protect against that potential issue.  Or just use a uuid package to allow dupes.

Comment: Yes, if you think there might be duplicate descriptions, use something else - perhaps have a state in the TaskList of the number of tasks created so far (including ones that have been deleted), and use that index as a new property, and use that property as the key. Or a UUID, sure.